# Favicon creation

Tags: favicon

I want to create an favicon that looks the best it can when displayed by the main browsers (including IE7) but has the smallest file size possible. What size and colour depth is best for each image involved?

I have just created a new icon with the following images within it.
16x16 bit (8 bit colour)
32x32 bit (8 bit colour)

Should I create any other images for either desktop shortcuts, Win7 taskbar pinning or any other use a browser or OS makes of it?

Note: This is not to do with whatever software you can use to create favicons

Comment: Why was this closed?  Was just looking for this exact question.... :-(

Comment: This article explains what's needed http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/understand-the-favicon/

Answer (score 1):

If you want all browsers to support it, it must be an icon file, .ico file extension.

If you're concerned about size i assume people are hitting your site over a slow connection.  If you put the file, named favicon.ico, in your root directory and do NOT include an html link tag to it, it will be loaded AFTER the rest of your site, so then you can comfortably include both a 32x32 and 16x16 version, I believe in one file.

You should read [this site](http://www.html-kit.com/support/favicon/image-size/),
and [this site](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon).

Answer (score 0):

just stick to 16x16 resolution.

Comment: Thanks. The 16x16 resolution image does not look so good when its a shortcut on the desktop or when it is pinned to the Win7 taskbar. Both of which my users do.